# Show Snackbar in Material Design 3 using Scaffold

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

Decided to try out ***Material Design 3*** in my new Jetpack Compose project. Everything was cozy until I needed to show a Snackbar when I hit a wall.

In ***MD2*** this was super-easy and you would show the snackbar in a Scaffold done with the `SnackbarHostState.showSnackbar()` function inside a Coroutine scope. I observed you only needed to import `androidx.compose.material.rememberScaffoldState` from Material Library.

```
import androidx.compose.material.rememberScaffoldState


@Composable
fun MyScreenInMaterial2() {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
}
```

When I try the same in ***MD3*** the `rememberScaffoldState()` function is not being resolved.
[image]

For those who have dived in MD3 world how do you show a Snackbar in a Scaffold? I have checked the docs and online resources but I haven't come across a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71363542/not-able-to-use-rememberscaffoldstate-in-android-compose-material3

Comment: Thx @MartinZeitler, looks like we will have to wait for MD Team to do something. I will leave the question here in case someone else comes across the same issue ...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here you have an example from [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#RangeSlider(kotlin.ranges.ClosedFloatingPointRange,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.ranges.ClosedFloatingPointRange,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.material3.SliderColors)).

```kotlin
val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
Scaffold(
    snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
    floatingActionButton = {
        var clickCount by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
            onClick = {
                // show snackbar as a suspend function
                scope.launch {
                    snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                        "Snackbar # ${++clickCount}"
                    )
                }
            }
        ) { Text("Show snackbar") }
    },
    content = { innerPadding ->
        Text(
            text = "Body content",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding).fillMaxSize().wrapContentSize()
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: Gosh, how did I miss this. **MDC3** eliminates `scaffoldState` parameter which you could use on MD2 like this: `scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar()`. You now need _remember { SnackbarHostState() }_ which you use like this `snackbarHostState.showSnackbar()`. So no more need for **ScaffoldState** on MD3!! Thx  @Damian

Comment: Avoid using a CoroutineScope here because you'll get a warning: `CoroutineCreationDuringComposition`. I've added an answer based on this one. TLDR: Replace `CoroutineScope` with `LaunchedEffect`.

Comment: So you just ignore the `it: SnackbarHostState` passed to `snackbarHost`'s lambda? I wouldn't call this an intuitive solution :-\ Why do they give us this parameter when they suggest ignorig it?

Answer (score 7):

*Bsed on [Damian Petla's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73006218/2823516).*

If you use a `CoroutineScope` then you'll get a warning saying `CoroutineCreationDuringComposition`.

[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect) suggests using `LaunchedEffect` instead to avoid this side-effect.

So the suggested code would look like this:

```
val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }

Scaffold(
    snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
    floatingActionButton = {
        var clickCount by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
            onClick = {
                LaunchedEffect(snackbarHostState) {
                    snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                        "Snackbar # ${++clickCount}"
                    )
                }
            }
        ) { Text("Show snackbar") }
    },
    content = { innerPadding ->
        Text(
            text = "Body content",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding).fillMaxSize().wrapContentSize()
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: This is right n Docs support it, thx for the insights

Comment: what is content? I have gone through docs and they don't explain what it is and why it is mandatory

Comment: @MuhammadSarimMehdi you have a Scaffold that is like the foundation of your view. And you want to see something in it, right? Well, that _something_ is the content.


In the [Scaffold's documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/scaffold#example) the `content` is explained.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, there's compile error with:

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

When calling the `LaunchedEffect` inside the `onClickChip` lambda.

There's an alternative options, inspired from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75594586/3763032)

For those wants to show the Compose Snackbar inside a lambda (w/o `@Composable`)

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun ScreenA() {
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val snackbarMessage = "Succeed!"
    val showSnackbar = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    LaunchedEffect(showSnackbar.value) {
        if (showSnackbar.value)
            snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(snackbarMessage)
    }
    Surface {
        Scaffold(
            snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState) },
        ) {
            ChipIcon(
                text = "Click me: ${showSnackbar.value}",
                onClickChip = {
                    // unable to use LaunchedEffect in here
                    showSnackbar.value = !showSnackbar.value
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

// Custom Composable
@Composable
fun ChipIcon(
    text: String,
    onClickChip: () -> Unit, // no @Composable, unable to use LaunchedEffect in this lambda
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(
                enabled = true,
                onClick = {
                    onClickChip()
                }
            ),
    ) {
        Text(text = text)
    }
}
```

> Observe the `showSnackbar.value` changes instead on `LaunchedEffect` for cancle/re-launch, then show snackbar if the `showSnackbar.value == true`, otherwise do nothing