# Should a custom SnackbarHost use the Scaffold's default SnackbarHostState or a custom one?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar

There are apparently two ways to initialize a custom `Snackbar`.

You can do this by using a custom `SnackbarHostState` and ignoree the default one passed to the lambda. (I found it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73006218/235671) question while trying to make it work for the first time.)

```kotlin
// ignores default SnackbarHostState
val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
Scaffold(
    snackbarHost = { it: SnackbarHostState -> 
        SnackbarHost(
            hostState = snackbarHostState, // <-- uses custom SnackbarHostState
        ) { snackbarData -> }
    },
    topBar = { },
    bottomBar = { }
) { innerPadding -> }
```

But then I thought it's weird that the first solution ignores the default `SnackbarHostState` so I tried to use it in place of the custom one and it turned out, this works too!

```kotlin
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    snackbarHost = { it: SnackbarHostState -> 
        SnackbarHost(
            hostState = it, // <-- uses default SnackbarHostState
        ) { snackbarData -> }
    },
    topBar = { },
    bottomBar = { }
) { innerPadding -> }
```

So now I'm wondering which one is correct? Are there any dis/advantages by using one or the other implementation?